# generating javascript alert in selenium using JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Things tried

```
String selectBook="abc"; 
String script="alert('"+selectBook+"' book does not exist');"; 
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript(script);
```

I want to alert the value of variable select book in alert along with the message.

Comment: print out "String script"... maybe you'll notice something off.

Comment: Printing script value gives: alert('abc' book does not exist');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes are closed incorrectly

```
String script="alert('"+selectBook+" book does not exist');";
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Hi @Grishma Did the above solution help you??